# Implicit conversion of method to Func in C#

Tags: c#

I have this function `printAll` that prints all elements of an `IEnumerable`

```
IEnumerable<A> printAll<A> (IEnumerable<A> able) {
    foreach (var a in able) {
        print (a);  
    }
    return able;
}
```

I also have a function `Fn.Compose` that composes functions defined as

```
Func<A,C> Compose<A,B,C> ( Func<B,C> g, Func<A,B> f ) {
    return x => g (f (x));
}
```

I use `Compose` it to get `f`

```
Fun<int, IEnumerable<int>> f = Fn.Compose (printAll, g);
```

where `g` is of type

```
Func<int,IEnumerable<int>>
```

and

At least in the editor get no warnings, but when I compile this error appears

> No overload for method `printAll' takes`0' arguments

which is strange because I am not calling `printAll` , I am just passing it as an argument.

**Edit**: Works if I cast

```
Compose (printAll as Func<IEnumerable<int>,IEnumerable<int>>, g);
```

but it should work with out it. Worst of all, this works

```
Compose (x => printAll(x), g);
```

Comment: how is `Fn.Compose` declared ?

Comment: `Compose`'s first parameter is probably an `Action` with no parameters. Since `printAll` takes a parameter, it cannot be automatically converted to an `Action`.

Comment: Compose takes 2 `Funcs` and returns a `Func` as shown in the edit version of the post.

Comment: Works for me as posted..

Comment: How are you invoking `f`? Can you show your usage?

Comment: Working fine in this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/hn12JE

Comment: Also working in this fiddle :P http://ideone.com/izAdEB

Comment: :(

Using Unity3D. Don't know if that might be it.

Comment: Can you show us how you are invoking `f`, please?

Comment: @wbennett Since `f` is just a `Func<int,IEnumerable<int>>` you can invoke it with any integer: for example `f (1)` in my case it prints `1 2 3 4 5 ..`

Comment: Thanks I misread that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with all of the generics action going on, the compiler cannot resolve the argument types. You have to be explicit

```
Func<int, IEnumerable<int>> f = Compose<int,IEnumerable<int>,IEnumerable<int>>(printAll, g);
```

I should clarify. It depends on the version of Visual Studio or the compiler you are using. Compiles fine in 2012, but needs to be explicit in 2008.  Not sure about other versions.

Comment: Seems Unity uses .NET 2.0 :(

Answer (score 0):

The inference system is probably unable to determine the type of `A`.

Have you tried explicitly listing `A` rather than the resultant type?

For instance `Fn.Compose(printAll<int>, g);`